# Looking for a word describing the act of a person passing an access machine that does not imply if it is an entry or exit

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am translating a computer program interface that deals with granting access to places and records entries and exits of employees. I need to find a word that describes the act of an employee using an access machine that does not imply wheter it is an entry or exit. The word I am looking for is supposed to describe the fact that someone went through the access point and the machine registered him/her.

The literal translation of the word used in the program is passages.
Is passage an acceptable word in this sense?

Comment: I think passage is fine, though it does not carry the checking part. The place in itself can be called "checkpoint" or "control point"  (as in "checkpoint charlie"). Maybe you could use transit check or transit control for the act.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The word itself does not have to carry the checking part. It would be great if it did, but it is not necessary. I am looking for a single word to use. Using something longer would require changing the program and my boss is not too happy about that.

Comment: Authentication.

Comment: Requests to name something (such as a variable) are out of scope. There are many reasons for this. One is that they come with baggage (such as "must be a single word" or "must be fewer than 10 characters") that cause good answers to be left unaccepted and accepted answers to be virtually useless to other people who visit the site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Passage

is fine, consider sub-definitions 5,6 and 7 from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/passage)

Sub-definitions from Collins

> 5. a journey, esp by ship ⇒ the outward passage took a week
> 6. the act or process of passing from one place, condition, etc, to another
> 7. the permission, right, or freedom to pass ⇒ to be denied passage through a country